# Regex with second forward slash not working ExpressJS routing

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have a bizarre error with ExpressJS routing. If I include a regex normally it will serve the correct page, so this works:

#### Route

```
app.get(/\/[a-z]+/, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

#### URL

```
http://localhost:8080/something
```

..

This, however, does not work:

#### Route

```
app.get(/\/[a-z/]+/, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

#### URL

```
http://localhost:8080/something/something
```

The correct file is served, but no resources are pulled into the page and the console logs this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

on the opening HTML tag.

Comment: You will have to escape `/` inside character class.

Comment: Nah doesn't solve the problem

Comment: As it is saying _Unexpected token <_, look for extra `<` you might have misplaced.